# find all the name using mysql query which start with the letter 'a'

Tags: mysql

I want to find the data from table artists where name is start with letter a, b, c.

```
i.e. 
My o/p should contain
Adam
Alan
Bob
Ben
Chris
Cameron

But not GlAin, doC, dolBie
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use like 'A%' expression, but if you want this query to run fast for large tables I'd recommend you to put number of first button into separate field with tiny int type.

Answer (score 39):

In MySQL use the `'^'` to identify you want to check the first char of the string then define the array [] of letters you want to check for.

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE name REGEXP '^[abc]'
```

Comment: REGEXP is a synonym for RLIKE so this answer is the same as the one given by @ZenOut.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
select * from artists where name like "A%" or name like "B%" or name like "C%"
```

Comment: No problem. Question title and body not 100% in agreement.

Answer (score 13):

One can also use `RLIKE` as below

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE name RLIKE '^[abc]';
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this simple select:

```
select * 
from artists 
where name like "a%"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for substr() functionality in MySql.

Basically, this function takes account of three parameters i.e.
substr(str,pos,len)

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php

```
SELECT * FROM artists 
WHERE lower(substr(name,1,1)) in ('a','b','c');
```

Answer (score 2):

try using **CHARLIST** as shown below:

```
select distinct name from artists where name RLIKE '^[abc]';
```

use distinct only if you want distinct values only.
To read about it Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

Comment: That only finds artists named “a”, “b” or “c”.

Comment: Incorrect @DourHighArch, the regular expression `'^[abc]'` means any name starting with a, b or c.

Comment: @JonP The expression originally posted was `[abc]`. The new expression is a copy of one posted a month ago.

Comment: Ach, it's confusing when people correct their posts isn't it!

Comment: Actually `[abc]` would give you any artist whose name contains a, b, or c.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE name >= 'a' and name < 'd'
```

will perform good, as long as name is indexed.