# Finding set of names starting from particular alphabet in php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, database

I am creating a social network site in which i want to send a message to a particular person but i want the list should appear in front of me of all the names when i type the first input alphabet from database(Mysql)

Comment: Well you'd be doing the fetching in SQL, which isn't even tagged.

Comment: "particular alphabet" - which alphabet? English, French, Chinese?

Comment: Please elaborate the question. This is not twitter. You can write long questions(atleast community can understand what you want).

Comment: THis question lacks enough details to be answered. You are working in PHP and need to get data from somewhere applying some filter. From where you are getting this data? SQL? Array? file? URL?

Please, be more detailed.

Comment: @St0rM-I am fetching it from Mysql

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use the `%` char for that:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'a%;
```

(selects all fields that start with "a" following a random number of random chars)

More information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the like function along with a wildcard

See this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951320/find-all-the-name-using-mysql-query-which-start-with-the-letter-a)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
like 'a%'
```

Postgresql

```
ilike 'a%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean fetching only one specific letter, or a set of specific letters.

If only one letter

```
select * from table where field like 'a%'
```

If you want to use an alphabet (list of letters)

```
select * from table where substring(field, 1, 1) IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```