# Why is this code not working "SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%'"

Tags: mysql

[image]

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%';
```

Comment: `LIKE` does not process regular expressions. Well... and that's not even a regular expression.

Comment: Wait... is this Oracle or MySQL? MySQL does not have the `VARCHAR2` data type.

Comment: Because mySql `LIKE` doesn't work like a regex. You should check the documentation, if you want to do your tests on SO, please respect the site's standards. You should describe precisely your problem and tools used, what is expected and what you get instead, and add the error if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou]';
```

The answer comes from: 
[find all the name using mysql query which start with the letter 'a'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951320/find-all-the-name-using-mysql-query-which-start-with-the-letter-a)

Documentation on REGEXP:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE 'a%' or CITY LIKE 'e%' or CITY LIKE 'i%' or CITY LIKE 'o%' or CITY LIKE 'u%'

Comment: Please try to format your _answer_, and add some **explanation** to it.  (see: [Style guide for Stack Overflow questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers) and/or [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)