# Confused about BETWEEN in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I have a table with test data like this:

```
+------------+----------+------------+
| PersonalNr | Vorname  | Nachname   |
+------------+----------+------------+
|          1 | Thorsten | Anker      |
|          2 | Michelle | Craft      |
|          3 | Sandra   | Bäcker     |
|          4 | Heinz    | Tölpel     |
|          5 | Horst    | Brot       |
|          6 | Merle    | Breitbarth |
|          7 | Boris    | Baum       |
|          8 | Emerich  | Adenauer   |
|          9 | Wilhelm  | Hase       |
|         10 | Nora     | Holzmann   |
|         11 | Winfried | Hildebrand |
|         12 | Jupp     | Garb       |
|         13 | Helene   | Braun      |
|         14 | Herwig   | Jaeger     |
|         15 | Jonathan | Berger     |
|         16 | Jimmy    | Gehrig     |
|         17 | Odelia   | Fischer    |
+------------+----------+------------+
```

When using BETWEEN on the column PersonalNr like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Fahrer WHERE PersonalNr BETWEEN 9 AND 12;
```

I get the result I expect:

```
+------------+----------+------------+
| PersonalNr | Vorname  | Nachname   |
+------------+----------+------------+
|          9 | Wilhelm  | Hase       |
|         10 | Nora     | Holzmann   |
|         11 | Winfried | Hildebrand |
|         12 | Jupp     | Garb       |
+------------+----------+------------+
```

while when using a query like

```
SELECT * FROM Fahrer WHERE Nachname BETWEEN "C" and "H";
```

The rows containing values starting with H are excluded from the result.

Where is my faulty reasoning if any?

Comment: `BETWEEN` does not use search patterns. That query is literally searching for strings greater than `C%` and less than `H%`, where the `%` is just a character, not a wildcard.

Comment: `'H%'` < any word (2 letters or more) starting with an H.

Comment: Try something like `SUBSTRING(Nachname, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'C' and 'H'`

Comment: @jarlh thanks - I guess this a "looked to long at it" problem. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951320/find-all-the-name-using-mysql-query-which-start-with-the-letter-a

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks - but I didn't even use % in my query. No clue why I wrote it here. Anyway: got it fixed thanks to jarlh

Comment: "I didn't even use % in my query."  - that sounds strange. The third query of your question contains a `%` - if you've used a different query, why not share that other query?

Comment: when asking questions, always copy and paste your code; do not retype it.

Comment: Yeah - happens. Just wanted fo fix the case of the sql keywords (select -> SELECT) and for whatever reason wrote the whole query instead. Happens.

Comment: You added the "correct answer" to your question, which you should not do (because that invalidated the question).   Another way to solve this is doing: `.....WHERE Nachname BETWEEN "C" and "Hzzzz";` (where `z` is the last possible character which can appear in a name`

Comment: Would have preferred to add it as an answer as well - but as someone closed it "for clarification" I was rendered unable to add the answer as... well.. an answer

Comment: You could also use `WHERE Nachname >= 'C' and Nachname < 'I'`. All names starting with 'H' are less than 'I'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One correct answer would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Fahrer WHERE SUBSTRING(Nachname,1,1) BETWEEN "C" AND "H";
```

(Thanks to @jarlh)

which worked for me.

Another option (in this scenario) would be to use

```
SELECT * FROM Fahrer WHERE Nachname BETWEEN "C" and "I";
```

instead.